# How do I override delete method for an inline model within django?

Tags: python, django, django-admin

I have a model 'B' that is linked to another model 'A' as an inline model, for use in my admin site. Now, whenever I delete an object of model 'B' associated with the corresponding object of model 'A' (via the admin site), I want to perform some more tasks at the backend. I was able to override the save function using a formset and then overriding the save_existing and save_new methods. How do I go about overriding the delete method for the inline admin model?

Answer (score 1):

I was able to get around by overriding the save() method for my model in the models.py itself.

Answer (score 1):

Use [`pre_delete`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/signals/#django.db.models.signals.pre_delete) or [`post_delete`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/signals/#django.db.models.signals.post_delete) signals to execute code before/after model is deleted:

```
from django.db.models.signals import pre_delete
from django.dispatch import receiver
from myapp.models import MyModel


@receiver(pre_delete, sender=MyModel)
def my_handler(sender, **kwargs):
    ...
```